# Convergence of gradient descent without bounded level set

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex, differentiable function. Suppose that there is a nonempty set of points that minimize $f$. If $\{x_k\}$ is the sequence produced by gradient descent with the Armijo rule, is it always true that $f(x_k) \rightarrow f(x^*)$?

From Proposition 1.2.1 from "Nonlinear Programming" by Bertsekas, we know that if $\{x_k\}$ is a sequence generated with the Armijo rule, every limit point will be a minimizer, so we have that $f(x_k) \rightarrow f(x^*)$. However, in the case where the level set $\{x: f(x) \leq f(x_0)\}$ is not bounded, then it's possible that no limit points exist.

Comment: There are various results of convergence of the backtracking armijo rule, and the Wikipage has a decent summary: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_line_search#Theoretical_guarantee_(for_gradient_descent). TLDR: For $f$ with Lipschitz gradient, convergence is guaranteed.

Comment: I would be nice to not have to assume Lipschitz gradient. Indeed, it is not necessary for Proposition 1.2.1. Intuitively I feel that convergence should be guaranteed for this case as well, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Results in the wiki-link assures that a convex $f \in C^1$  with countably many minimizers also converges. It's hard to see how one in general can guarantee that the gradient vanishes in the limit if the gradient isn't continuous.

Comment: In Lyapunov stability theory, there's a famous example of why level sets need to be bounded — level sets of the [form](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2+*+y%5E2+%3D+1) $x^2 y^2 = c^2$. In the limit, we obtain the union of the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis, which is not very useful if one wishes to conclude that the origin is stable. Not sure if this helps you in any way.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Is that function convex though?

Comment: @user253846 Certainly not convex. I was focusing on boundedness.

Comment: @ms_ Convexity implies the derivative is continuous. However, I don't think the proof by Bertsekas requires that the derivative is continuous.

Comment: @user253846 continuous almost everywhere by Rademacher. What if the minimizers belong to the null set.